# Repeating a SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql

This `SELECT` statement is working just fine but I'd like to be able to repeat it to further refine the search.

```
SELECT id1 
FROM table1 
WHERE id2 IN (SELECT id 
              FROM table2 
              WHERE name="country" 
                AND value="Mexico")
```

For instance, if I wanted to find only locations in Mexico that had 'Beaches' which would be:

```
name="features" AND value="Beaches"
```

...how would I go about paring the results down further with my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Am i missing something?  just add those filters to your query (for which ever table where those values are stored)

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more on the "refining".  As stated, you are asking for `value="Mexico" AND value="Beaches"`, which is an empty result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to execute a new query and just add the additional filtering.  It would be possible to filter "manually" in the client application, but that would likely be less efficient for most situations.  So run a new query with more restrictions:

```
SELECT id1 FROM table1 WHERE id2 IN 
        (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE 
               name="country" AND 
               value="Mexico" AND
               name2 = "features" AND 
               value2 = "Beaches" )
```

Note that I changed the two new column names to something different (the original query result would not have contained those other values given the original names).  If by "refine", you want to add then perhaps the query should be:

```
SELECT id1 FROM table1 WHERE id2 IN 
        (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE 
               ( name="country" AND 
               value="Mexico" ) OR
               ( name = "features" AND 
               value = "Beaches" ))
```

Comment: Mark, OP wanted records that were fullfilling both conditions. What you provide is alternative.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek:  The first query is an attempt to show what the OP specifically requested.  And, yes, the second is an alternative.  The OP cannot actually be fulfilled with a non-empty result set as stated.  To follow the request exactly, the OP wants "value="Mexico" AND value="Beaches", which is an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Vecta, you need to extend your query by adding additional INs:

```
SELECT id1 
FROM table1 
WHERE id2 IN (SELECT id 
          FROM table2 
          WHERE name="country" 
            AND value="Mexico")
AND id2 IN (SELECT id 
          FROM table2 
          WHERE name="featues" 
            AND value="Beach")
```

Take into consideration though, that this will lead to performance decrease very quickly. :-)